# Executing a stored procedure once an hour automatically

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I want to execute the below stored procedure once every hour automatically from vb.net program

Any help is greatly appreciated

I have written the following stored procedure as below.

```
create procedure dbo.test as  
BEGIN  
   Select * from dbo.testtable  
END
```

That stored procedure is returning huge results, then causing the performance issue on application loading.

So instead of calling the same results on each button click events, I would like to call the stored procedure once every hour and have to re-use the dataset by using some state management technique like `Session` or `View State`.

`TestAspx.vb` file - maintaining the result in `Session`

**Method1**

```
PrivateSub test()  
        dim ds as dataset
        ds = objtestdata.test() //From here am accessing the datalayer testdata.vb file
        Session("Testdata") = ds
    End Sub
```

**Loading the Session data in dropdown control**

**Method2**

```
PrivateSub loaddropdown()
            dropdowncontrol.DataSource = Session("Testdata")
            dropdowncontrol.DataBind()
end sub
```

`Testdata.vb` file - calling stored procedure from data layer

```
Public Function test() As DataSet
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd As DbCommand

        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

            cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.test")

            ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)

        Return ds

End Function
```

So by taking the `Session("TestDate")` I can use this dataset in multiple button click loadings.

I have to handle the returning dataset in `testaspx.vb` file as below

How could I run this whole process every hour?

Help me in this regard.
Thank You,

Comment: What about doing the hourly stored procedure executions within a service, in that service you can insert the hourly data into another table and use that table from within your vb app.

Comment: If that **stored procedure** (it's **stored** - as in **stored** inside your database) returns *huge result* as you say - you **MOST DEFINITELY** don't want to store that into the view state!

Answer (score 2):

Your stored procedure simply retrieves a whole database table.  If this operation is slow just because the table has an enormous number of records, there is no way of caching the data in the database that could help you.

You should double check that you really need all that data loaded into the application all the time.  If you do, your application will always load slowly - there is no way around it.

While you can create an [asynchronous thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289178%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), that is probably a solution inferior to implementing a refresh button so that the user can control when reloads happen.

Finally, if `testtable` is a view rather than a table, and it returns small data slowly, you should focus on profiling and fixing the performance of the view.

**Edit**:

You can configure SQL Server Agent job to execute a slow running procedure hourly, even when your application is not running.  This assumes that you are NOT using the Express edition which does not include SQL Server Agent.

```
EXEC sp_add_job N'MyHourlyJob'
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'MyHourlyJob',
    @step_name = N'Update_Something',
    @command = N'EXEC p_Update_Something', 
EXEC sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'HourlyJobs' ,
    @freq_interval = 1,
    @freq_type = 4,            -- every @freq_interval days
    @freq_subday_type = 8,     -- every @freq_subday_interval hours
    @freq_recurrence_factor = 1,
    @freq_subday_interval = 1
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'MyHourlyJob',
   @schedule_name = N'HourlyJobs' ;
```

Comment: Stored procedure is very highlevel. Yes, I have to load whole data into application.From the SP side we did performance tuning too.Thank You for you suggestions.

Comment: @OverflowUser - If the stored procedure is complex, and produces relatively small data (less than 10000 records) slowly, it would help listing the whole SP code, schema of all tables it uses, all existing indexes, and the query plan, as part of the question.  I was simply looking at the SP that you already posted and that was a one liner.

Comment: Please ignore the SP side performance. Just for example I written the SP.Bottom line is "I have to execute a stored procedure once an hour automatically by using .net"

Comment: @OverflowUser - performance duly ignored, "by using .net" ignored as well, as I assume that you probably do not want those hourly jobs to stop while your application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework version you are using. But you can use the MemoryCache on .Net4 or Http cache on .Net2.

If you are running on .NET 4 you can use MemoryCache to do the job for you.

```
public static class MyBigDataCache
{
    private const string RegionName= "myBigDataRegion";

    // key could by the username...
    public static DataTable GetMyData(string key)
    {
        // try the cache
        var data = (DataTable) MemoryCache.Default.Get(key, RegionName);

        // nothing in cache...
        if (data == null)
        {
            // read from db
            data = ReadDataFromDb(key);

            // create the cache policy to evict this key after 1 hour.
            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy()
                {
                    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(60)
                };

            // add to cache
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(new CacheItem(key, data, RegionName), policy);
        }

        return data;
    }

    private static DataTable ReadDataFromDb(String key)
    {
        // load your data here...
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you're running on .NET2 you can use the Http cache. Example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, data, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default,
                                          null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SqlDependencyCache might fit your needs well, if you just want to load the resultset once, and have changes to it propagated to your app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx